# Simple pusher error after push notification: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: push-notification, pusher

I just create a simple code

I made an android app with kotlin
I add this code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "my_id")
        PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello")
    }
```

This is my notification push on terminal

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx"
    -X POST "https://my_id.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/my_id/publishes"
      -d '{"interests":["hello"],"fcm":{"notification":{"title":"Hello","body":"Hello, world!"}}}'
{"publishId":"pubid-myid"}
```

when I try push a notification on terminal, my apps get force close

Here is my error message

```
I/FCMMessageReceiver: Got a valid pusher message.
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.pusher.pushnotifications.fcm.MessagingService$WrappedFirebaseMessagingService>
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.muffin.cobanotif, PID: 11211
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pusher.pushnotifications.fcm.MessagingService$WrappedFirebaseMessagingService
        at com.pusher.pushnotifications.fcm.MessagingService.<init>(MessagingService.kt:72)
        at com.pusher.pushnotifications.fcm.EmptyMessagingService.<init>(MessagingService.kt:108)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2866)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

And my dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.4.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the following firebase messaging to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

This is described here:

https://pusher.com/docs/beams/getting-started/android/sdk-integration#update-your-app-level-gradle-config